# How to change the color of PHP tags in Brackets

Tags: php, editor, adobe-brackets

I am working on a custom theme for Brackets (http://brackets.io/) and I am wondering if there is a way that I can specifically change the color of php tags. The parts between asterisks below would be red:

```
*<?php* echo 'test'; *?>*
```

I have been looking at several themes .less files and I do not see how this has been accomplished. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

This is not for display on a website. I am developing a theme for Brackets which is a code editor. I want php to stand out more effectively than the standard way that php is displayed in the editor. Brackets uses LESS for styling parts of the editor.

Here is more information about Brackets theme development: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Creating-Themes

Comment: What do you want exactly? Do you want to chage the color of `<?php` and `?>` ? (changing color of your codes)

Comment: Exactly. Imagine something similar to the way that Dreamweaver displays php.

Comment: well use Dreamweaver :) !! What is the name of your software programming now ?

Comment: aha, Do you want to simulates a programming environment ?

Comment: Brackets. I am developing a theme for use in Brackets. http://brackets.io/

Answer (score 0):

The class to change php tag in Brackets themes is `.cm-meta`, this also change html doctype, css vendor prefixes and maybe another tag or property.