# Bracket.io - PHP Syntax highlighter

Tags: syntax-highlighting, adobe-brackets

I am running the latest version of Adobe Brackets.io (v1.14.1) and would like to be able to highlight PHP tags (eg. `<?PHP` and `?>`) in a different color (eg. red).

Now, I can appreciate that Brackets is focused on design and CSS aspects of web-development, but having searched this question beforehand I found that this is a rather popular request, hence was wondering if there has been update on this matter?

I downloaded extension "PHP SmartHints" reading that it would allow for this feature, but sadly does not.

Appreciate any recommendations on how to set this up.
Thanks

EDIT: this questions was asked almost 5 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360558/how-to-change-the-color-of-php-tags-in-brackets) but has no accepted answer.